# CygWin SSHD and UTF-8 BOM

Tags: configuration, utf-8, cygwin-sshd

The CygWin ssh server configuration file "config_sshd" seems to need to be written minus a byte order marker. The server will accept UTF-8 but obviously becomes confused if it sees what it thinks is junk data at the top of the file. Is there any way around this or will I just have to deal?

I personally prefer my text files to have a BOM as it solves many problems when generating them from redirection at the command line.

Addendum

This question has been moved on advice from 'Stack Overflow' to here.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I suggest asking this question on the Cygwin list, cygwin@cygwin.com.  The Cygwin sshd maintainer is there, along with many other knowledgeable people.

Comment: MANY thanks Andrew - That is very cool to know. It is good to have that kind of 'direct-line' to the programmers.